# Windows 10 "the device /device/harddisk0/dr0 has a bad block" but WORKS in safe mode desktop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

Suddenly my Windows 10 pro became unresponsive and I noticed System error `the device /device/harddisk0/dr0 has a bad block` in Event Log Viewer. As a precautions, I decided to backup my entire 500 GB drive (divided in several partitions) in case of physical bad block/sector. But when I tried to copy from Windows Explorer to external storage. It was too slow to continue and in Event Log Viewer, it was keep adding same error every 8/10 seconds even though `chkdsk /R /F` for a given partition/volume show no error, no bad sector, no further action required.

Then I boot my Win 10 in safe mode and to my surprise I was able to copy entire hard drive (skipping system/OS drive) to external storage without causing any single error in Event Log Viewer. Also copy operation was at normal speed as oppose to normal desktop boot as mentioned earlier.

**Why I am able to access hard disk normally from safe mode desktop and not from normal boot desktop?**

After taking backup I boot into command prompt with USB Win 10 installation media and I tried to run `chkdsk /R /F` on each volume. It succeed for each volume except system/OS volume. On OS volume it finished with an error `an unspecified error occurred (766f6c756d652e63 470)`

**How can I fix this so that it works normally on normal boot?**

Answer (score 2):

Boot into Safe Mode, then choose Advanced Option reboot (to boot froma LIVE USB OS), then download Hirens bootCD, then go to LIVE MINI XP, boot up, scan HDD with VICTORIA note the block numbers that appear damaged/BAD BLOCK/, then just cut/remap them out from the BLOCK MAP, and move them at the end of the DRIVE and make that space unallocated.

Then when you're done, you will need to do "sfc /scannow" and the usual BOOTREC fixes, should work.

This is just a precaution, best bet is to scan your PC from the LIVE CD with HDDSCAN/VICTORIA and/or from DOS mode MHDD, to see how badly damaged the drive is.

If you see Logical Bad blocks (are not to worryabout, that is just a lot of data overwritten in that spot, and chkdsk fixes that, or a re-install).

If you see "unconscious", "X", "unresponsive", "DARK bad block" means Physical, which means either you cut it out and remap, or you plan for a new HDD and start to copy data from that HDD ASAP, to a fresh HDD.